# Стоит ли ставить Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Стоит ли ставить Xcode 6?

Могу ли я поставить Xcode 6 вместе с 5ой версией? И вообще, стоит ли сейчас ставить новую версию?

Просто для основной работы хотелось бы пока оставаться на стабильной 5-ой версии, а 6-ая версия нужна ради Swift'а:)

Comment: Да. Единственный минус, который пока не знаю как побороть - он становится дефолтной программой , которая открывает .xcodeproj/.xcworkspace, и обратно на Xcode 5 даже через настройки не хочет меняться (но вручную через меню правой кнопки можно открыть старым).

Comment: А вот так - правой кнопкой вызываете контекстное меню и выбираете там “Свойства”. В открывшемся окошке свойств секция “Открывать в программе”.

В выпадающем списке перечислены все программы, которые теоретически способны открыть файлы данного типа. Если нужной программы нет в списке, нажмите “Выбрать программу”.

После этого останется нажать кнопку “Настроить”. Система спросит у вас подтверждение и поменяет программу по умолчанию не только для данного файла, но и для всех файлов с таким же расширением.

Comment: Добавил немаловажную деталь в свой ответ.

Comment: @AlessandroDP, фиг-то сдва! Сами пробовали? После нажатия "Change all" он каким-то чудесным образом вертает назад новый Xcode по дефолту). Команды от @AlexDenisov не помогают от этого :(. У меня такая петрушка кстати и со старыми бетами была.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы можете скачать `Xcode 6 Beta` с [портала разработчиков](https://developer.apple.com) и поставить его рядом как отдельное приложение.

'Старый' Xcode при этом не сломается.

**UPD:**

После установки нужно будет указать какой `Xcode` использовать, периодически придется менять:

```
$ xcode-select -print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Чтобы сменить обратно:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```